# Cache locality in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a stream of data, containing a key, that I need to mix and match with data associated with that key. Each key belongs to a partition, and each partition can be loaded from a database.

Data is quite big and only a few hundred out of hundreds of thousands partitions can fit in a single task manager.

My current approach is to use `partitionCustom` based on the `key.partition` and cache the partition data inside a `RichMapFunction` to mix and match without reloading the data of the partitions multiple times.

When the number of message rate on a same partition gets too high, I hit a hot-spot/performance bottleneck.

What tools do I have in Flink to improve the throughput in this case?

Are there ways to customize the scheduling and to optimize the job placements based on setup time on the machines, and maximum processing time history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like (a) your DB-based data is also partitioned, and (b) you have skew in your keys, where one partition gets a lot more keys than other partitions.

Assuming the above is correct, and you've done code profiling on your "mix and match" code to make that reasonably efficient, then you're left with manual optimizations. For example, if you know that keys in partition X are much more common, you can put all of those keys in one partition, and then distribute the remaining keys amongst the other partitions.

Another approach is to add a "batcher" operator, which puts up to N keys for the same partition into a group (typically this also needs a timeout to flush, so data doesn't get stuck). If you can batch enough keys, then it might not be so bad to load the DB data on demand for the partition associated with each batch of keys.

Comment: Thanks, yes a) and b) are correct. I would like to try the approach of adaptive balancing the assigned keys based on recent historic data distribution. How would I go to do that? Assuming I only need to know the `Map[partition, load]` of the last 15 minutes to optimise the load, how should I do that in Flink? With a probably suboptimal `countWindowAll.aggregate` I could collect the state, and optimise in a map function. How would I go than to send the optimised plan back, every 15', to the processing part pipeline?

Comment: The problem with dynamic partitioning is that when your workflow has to restore from a checkpoint, Flink doesn't know where to send state, as that needs to be partitioned the same as the keys that are processed when generating the state. If you have no state or no checkpointing, then it could be possible to have a side stream of just keys that you use to calc optimal partitioning, and that result is broadcast to a "partition assigning" operator.